# Having issue while merging graph in xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am trying to merge two graphs in xlsxwriter.

1 : a line graph
2 : a stacked graph having y2 axis.

While merging for the second graph the staring value is coming from the negative value of the line graph. Like below image. I want it start from x axis only i.e from 0. Please find the code i hv used for both graphs.

```
line_chart.set_x_axis({

    'name_font': {'size': 14, 'bold': True},
    'major_gridlines': {'visible': False},
    'major_tick_mark': 'none',
    'minor_tick_mark': 'none'

})

line_chart.set_y_axis({

    'name': 'Sales',
    'name_font': {'size': 14, 'bold': True},
    'major_gridlines': {'visible': False},
    'major_tick_mark': 'none',
    'minor_tick_mark': 'none',

})

line_chart.add_series({

    'name': ' ',
    'categories': '=data_sheet!$F$2:$F$25',
    'values': '=data_sheet!$D$2:$D$25',
    'line': {'color': '#FFCC00'},
    'marker': {'type': 'square',
               'border': {'color': 'red'},
               'fill': {'color': 'red'}
               },

})

bar_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column', 'subtype': 'stacked'})

bar_chart.set_x_axis({

    'name_font': {'size': 14, 'bold': True},
    'major_gridlines': {'visible': False},
    'major_tick_mark': 'none',
    'minor_tick_mark': 'none'

})

bar_chart.set_y2_axis({

    'name': 'Traffic',
    'name_font': {'size': 14, 'bold': True},
    'major_gridlines': {'visible': False},
    'major_tick_mark': 'none',
    'minor_tick_mark': 'none'

})

bar_chart.add_series({
    'name': '',
    'fill': {'color': 'white'},
    'categories': '=data_sheet!$F$2:$F$25',
    'values': '=data_sheet!$B$2:$B$25',
    'y2_axis': True,
})

bar_chart.add_series({
    'name': '',
    'fill': {'color': '#117A9A'},
    'categories': '=data_sheet!$F$2:$F$25',
    'values': '=data_sheet!$A$2:$A$25',
    'y2_axis': True,
})

line_chart.combine(bar_chart)
line_chart.set_legend({'position': 'low'})
line_chart.set_size({'width': 1025, 'height': 360})
line_chart.set_chartarea({'border': {'none': True}})
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Questions need to be about code - see this list of [allowed topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you have a specific programming question, please post the code and where you're having trouble. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Michael Delgado. I hv added the codes in the question.